# Tracker.autorun only runs once

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-tracker

Here is what I am currently working with

```
class FooComponent extends Component {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.state = {
      model: this.getModel()
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unmounted = true;
    this._modelComputation && this._modelComputation.stop();
    super.componentWillUnmount && super.componentWillUnmount();
  }

  getModel() {
    const model = {};

    this._modelComputation && this._modelComputation.stop();

    this._modelComputation = Tracker.autorun((computation) => {
      const { id } = this.props;
      const data = id && Collection.findOne(id);

      if (data) {
        Object.assign(model, data);
        !this._unmounted && this.forceUpdate();
      }
    });

    return model;
  }

  ...

}
```

Unfortunately, the reactive model does not work, and `Tracker.autorun` does not execute the function when the model is updated in the database. From the documentation, [`Collection.findOne`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne) should be reactive, right?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Why isn't `Tracker` monitoring the DB model? Why isn't the function re-evaluating `Collection.findOne` when the DB changes?

---

### ** Edit **

When updating the DB, I do see the collection change through `meteortoys:allthings`, but `autorun` is not re-executed.

Comment: This is a little vague. What exactly is happening that you expect to trigger the autorunning function? And have you tried [`Tracker.flush`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-flush)?

Comment: @Alex from what I [read](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne), `findOne` is supposed to be reactive, therefore any change in the database is supposed to invalidate the computation and re-execute the `autorun` function, no? As I stated, it does not work, and the function is not called when the database is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how [`tracker-react`](https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react/blob/master/Tracker.js) implements it, I changed my code like so

```
class FooComponent extends Component {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.state = {
      model: this.getModel()
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unmounted = true;
    this._modelComputation && this._modelComputation.stop();
    super.componentWillUnmount && super.componentWillUnmount();
  }

  getModel() {
    const model = {};

    this._modelComputation && this._modelComputation.stop();

    this._modelComputation = Tracker.nonreactive(() => {
      return Tracker.autorun((computation) => {
        const { id } = this.props;
        const data = id && Collection.findOne(id);

        if (data) {
          Object.assign(model, data);
          !this._unmounted && this.forceUpdate();
        }
      });
    });

    return model;
  }

  ...

}
```

I don't fully understand why, but it works, now.